# How to monitor ajax request (sent by vuejs) in iOS native UIWebView?

Tags: ios, ajax, uiwebview

How to monitor the ajax request send by the Vuejs( or other one-page-app ) from native iOS app?

To monitor the regular HTTP request from the `UIWebView`, I should use the method of `UIWebViewDelegate`，

**such as:**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

but I found I can't get **touch event** through that method when I click the web page, because the page is actually not reload, It's Ajax request.

Thanks!